# JQGRID + Timer + setGroupHeaders = multiple header grouping rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm looking for a few pointers. I'm building a HTML page which has a 60 second timer (javascript) which will refresh jqGrid (v4.2.0) with latest data from my server. I have it working fine and wanted to add the new setGroupHeaders option to group fields together. I placed the code in gridcomplete to add header grouping but i'm getting duplicate headers every 60 seconds. I'm wondering where is the best place to trigger the creation of the header groupings after the grid is reloaded with out getting duplicates?

Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ckTimer = setTimeout("sendTimer();", 1000);
});

function sendTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById('currentDay1').innerHTML = d.toDateString() + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById('currentDay2').innerHTML = d.toDateString() + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + d.toLocaleTimeString();
    var sec = d.getSeconds();
    ckTimer = setTimeout("sendTimer();", (60 - sec) * 1000);
    jQuery("#Report2").jqGrid().trigger('reloadGrid');
    if (rptframe)
        if (rptframe.reload)
            rptframe.reload();
}

    $(function () {
        jQuery("#Report2").jqGrid({
            url: 'DashboardHandler.ashx?act=DetailReport',
            datatype: 'json',
            height: 250,
            width: 1200,
            colNames: ['Interval', 'Volume (Offered)', 'Service Level', 'Average Speed To Answer', 'Abandon Rate', 'Average Handle Time', ' ', 'Volume (Offered)', 'Service Level', 'Average Speed To Answer', 'Abandon Rate', 'Average Handle Time', '', ''],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Interval', index: 'Interval', width: 125, sortable: false, align: "left" },
                { name: 'TSGVolume', index: 'TSGVolume', width: 100, sortable: false, align: "center" },
                { name: 'TSGCalcSLA', index: 'TSGCalcSLA', width: 100, sortable: false, align: "center" },
                { name: 'TSGASA', index: 'TSGASA', width: 100, sortable: false, align: "center" },
                { name: 'TSGAbnd', index: 'TSGAbnd', width: 100, sortable: false, align: "center" },
                { name: 'TSGAHT', index: 'TSGAHT', width: 100, sortable: false, align: "center" },
                { name: 'space', index: 'space', width: 50, sortable: false, align: "center" },
                { name: 'SCVolume', index: 'SCVolume', width: 100, sortable: false, align: "center" },
                { name: 'SCCalcSLA', index: 'SCCalcSLA', width: 100, sortable: false, align: "center" },
                { name: 'SCASA', index: 'SCASA', width: 100, sortable: false, align: "center" },
                { name: 'SCAbnd', index: 'SCAbnd', width: 100, sortable: false, align: "center" },
                { name: 'SCAHT', index: 'SCAHT', width: 100, sortable: false, align: "center" },
                { name: 'TSGASA_H', index: 'TSGASA_H', width: 0, sortable: false, align: "center", hidden: true },
                { name: 'SCASA_H', index: 'SCASA_H', width: 0, sortable: false, align: "center", hidden: true }
            ],
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [100, 250, 500],
            pager: '#Report2Pager',
            viewrecords: true,
            gridComplete: setClr
        })
        jQuery("#Report2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#Report2Pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
    });
    jQuery("#Report2").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
        useColSpanStyle: false,
        groupHeaders: [
                { startColumnName: 'TSGVolume', numberOfColumns: 5, titleText: 'TSG' },
                { startColumnName: 'SCVolume', numberOfColumns: 5, titleText: 'Solution Center' }
            ]
    });

function setClr() {
        var i, val;
        for (i = 1; i <= 27; i++) {
            val = $('#Report2').jqGrid('getRowData', i);
            if (val["TSGCalcSLA"] < 70)
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "TSGCalcSLA", '', 'red-highlight');
            else if (val["TSGCalcSLA"] > 80)
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "TSGCalcSLA", '', 'green-highlight');
            else
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "TSGCalcSLA", '', 'yellow-highlight');

            if (val["SCCalcSLA"] < 70)
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "SCCalcSLA", '', 'red-highlight');
            else if (val["SCCalcSLA"] > 80)
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "SCCalcSLA", '', 'green-highlight');
            else
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "SCCalcSLA", '', 'yellow-highlight');

            if (val["TSGASA_H"] > 60)
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "TSGASA", '', 'red-highlight');
            else if (val["TSGASA_H"] <= 30)
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "TSGASA", '', 'green-highlight');
            else
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "TSGASA", '', 'yellow-highlight');

            if (val["SCASA_H"] > 60)
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "SCASA", '', 'red-highlight');
            else if (val["SCASA_H"] <= 30)
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "SCASA", '', 'green-highlight');
            else
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "SCASA", '', 'yellow-highlight');

            if (val["TSGAbnd"] > 4.6)
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "TSGAbnd", '', 'red-highlight');
            else if (val["TSGAbnd"] <= 4.4)
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "TSGAbnd", '', 'green-highlight');
            else
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "TSGAbnd", '', 'yellow-highlight');

            if (val["SCAbnd"] > 4.6)
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "SCAbnd", '', 'red-highlight');
            else if (val["SCAbnd"] <= 4.4)
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "SCAbnd", '', 'green-highlight');
            else
                $('#Report2').jqGrid('setCell', i, "SCAbnd", '', 'yellow-highlight');
        }
            jQuery("#Report2").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
                useColSpanStyle: false,
                groupHeaders: [
                { startColumnName: 'TSGVolume', numberOfColumns: 5, titleText: 'TSG' },
                { startColumnName: 'SCVolume', numberOfColumns: 5, titleText: 'Solution Center' }
            ]
            });
    };
    function reload() {
        jQuery("#Report2").jqGrid().trigger('reloadGrid');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had multiple headers because the script tag in which I was using `setGroupHeaders` was inside the `div` used to display my jQgrid.

And this div was the div of a `jqueryui Dialog`.

So each time I was opening my dialog through a button, a new `groupHeader` was added.

To solve this problem, **I have moved the script tag outside the dialog div tag**.

I hope it will help someone else.

### Solution :

```
<div id="dialog_div">
    <table id="my_grid"></table>
    <div id="grid_pager"></div>
</div>

<script>
  // Initialize the grid here
</script>
```